# Multi document printing from document library?

Tags: 2007, document-library

Is there any one have solution for print multiple documents from Document library? User has option to select multiple documents or single document or inside folder.

I found commercial product "Unbounded Printing Services for SharePoint". But is so expensive. Please share me if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the document library in Explorer View, highlight the file(s) that you desire to print, right click, Print.